# Dynamic site, access session in global

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

Hello i am currently developing a kind of wiki system for my school, this system uses sub domains to find what course the wiki belongs to. example math1.wiki.com will be the course Math 1.
Now all these wikis use the same database and are given a wiki id, to find what data to load.

Here is the code i use to find the wiki id.
Global.asax

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        var database = new DataContext();
        IWikiRepository rep = new WikiRepository(database);
        IWikiService service = new WikiService(rep);

        var domain = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
        var port = "";
        if (domain.Contains(':'))
        {
            var tmp = domain.Split(':');
            domain = tmp[0];
            port = tmp[1];
        }
        var split = domain.Split('.');
        var subdomain = split[0];

     //   if (subdomain == "localhost")
     //       subdomain = "wiki1";

        var wiki = service.GetSite(subdomain);

        if (wiki == null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return;
        }

        Session["CurrentWiki"] = wiki;
    }
```

This is all fine, but i want to make the mvc system send a 404 request if no wiki was found for the subdomain. But this can not only be done in session_start() as it only runs once per session i have therefor tryed using Application_BeginRequest, but sadly do i not have access to the sessions in the method.

Do any one know how i can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why can't you just make a custom function that you call at the start of the main page to determine if the wiki exists and if not, redirect/error page/whatever.  If it's a custom function, you can just recall it when necessary.

Comment: What if the person uses a link and goes directly to another controller? Then would the site not be checked, and open up for errors!